# Any Workflow frameworks for Django/Python with active development?

Tags: python, django, workflow

Tried searching. But, what ever Django/Python packages I find, have no development going on.

Including the featured [GoFlow : a workflow engine for django](http://code.google.com/p/goflow/downloads/list). The latest update on this was in sept 2008!

So, are there any Workflow frameworks for Django/Python with active development?

Comment: Here is i did some investigation what workflow libraries for django are active now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795328/workflow-frameworks-for-django/25717038#25717038

Answer (score 1):

See django-packages:

- [Workflow](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/workflow/)
- [FSM](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/finite_state_machine/) might also work for you

Comment: [Workflow](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/workflow/) as I had pointed out does not have active development going on. Looking into [FSM](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/finite_state_machine/)..

Comment: Yep, FSM packages are maintained. Personally, I like FSM pattern more.

Comment: For the time being I will be writing my own WorkFlow/FSM module. Thanks for the links. +1