# does Django have something similar to spring web flow?

Tags: django, web, spring-webflow

The purpose is to create a stateful web applications with controlled navigation. 
There is a clear start and an end point.
The user must go through a set of screens in a specific order.
Once complete it shouldn't be possible to repeat a transaction accidentally.

Comment: Check out on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795328/workflow-frameworks-for-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't test that particular lib but it seems well suited for what you need:

http://code.google.com/p/django-stateful/

Answer (score 2):

Check the workflow section on [django awesome packages list](https://github.com/rosarior/awesome-django#workflows)

`django-flows` looks like most close substitution for spring web flow.

But build-in [django wizard forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) a fairly lightweight and suitable for many basic cases.

Comment: I just did investigation, what we have now for workflows in django - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795328/workflow-frameworks-for-django/25717038#25717038