# Building a django based request ticket System

Tags: django

I want to build a django based request ticket system where a front end user will put a request to the system. The request will then flow to a number of support staffs in the backend with an option to accept/deny help to the front end user. Selecting yes should produce a reply window to the support executive in which he/she can type his/her comments. More than one support executive can reply to the user. The front end user may see the replies in his account. Any help with this project will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This questions seems extremely general. Do you have any specific questions and/or code that you have already written that may need some advice or input? Otherwise, it would be hard to help you without writing the entire application for you. What you are asking for is very possible, but it is not a quick-answer type question.

Comment: Do you've any idea how to implement? or any code?

Comment: If you have plans to make the ticket processing more complicated you can use one of solutions for workflow implementation in django -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795328/workflow-frameworks-for-django

Answer (score 1):

Although I stated that the question is vague above, here is a workflow that may be able to get you started if you have not done so already.

The solution seems pretty straightforward:

1) Create an appropriate `url` in your `urls.py` that will represent the page users will do this action.

2) Create a `Ticket` model in you Django models. Perhaps something like this:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    admin_response = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

3) Create a `view` in your `views.py`, passing in a `form` through the context, as well as all of the possible answers (e.x. `queryset = Ticket.objects.filter(user=request.user, accepted=True)`).

4) Render a `POST` form on the user's frontend in the `.html` file.

5) Render the answers in your `.html` file (e.x. `{% for ticket in queryset %}{{ ticket.admin_response }}{% endfor %}`).

Once the user submits a ticket, any of your admins can enter their response through the Django Admin, which will then be shown to the asking user via step 5.

Keep in mind that this gets more complicated if the user wants a comment thread (i.e. more than just one question and one response).

Comment: You've basically just described any Django app...!

Comment: I updated the code for you to include a model sample. Again, your question is extremely vague, so the best I can give is a blanketing solution without writing the entire thing myself.

Comment: It's not my question - I've actually flagged it ass to broad. I just found it amusing that your answer is basically any Django intro condensed.

Comment: Oh, ha - I thought you were the OP. Well, in the case of the OP, when I see a question that is this vague, I assume a lack of knowledge, so I try to provide at least a little bit of a window into the workflow. Thanks for clarifying, though.

Comment: Have you seen this Django app: [https://github.com/rossp/django-helpdesk](https://github.com/rossp/django-helpdesk)?

Comment: Yes and it does't work properly. Errors out when submitting a ticket. No date/time picker and more.

Comment: @Stryker -- I have deployed django-helpdesk in AWS and it works just fine. It has a date/time picker and bunch of other features. Are you sure you configured it correctly? What version did you attempt to deploy?